# picture fadeout with transition

Tags: html, css, transition

when I scroll down 450px the picture fades in as wanted but when I scroll up again it is just gone with no transition. I guess its just something with the transition. here is the code and a gif so you can see what i mean:

https://gyazo.com/b27b6ba31e29a16f8cd0b862ffbfc1a0

INDEX

```
<div class="logo_aftereffects"></div>
 <div class="logo_premierepro"></div>

        <script>
              $(window).scroll(function() {
                 if($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
                    $('div#myTopnav').addClass('scrolled');
                    $('a').addClass('scrolled2');
                 if($(window).scrollTop() >= 430) {
                    $('div.sidebar').addClass('scrolled3');
                    $('div.logo_premierepro').addClass('scrolled4');
                    $('div.logo_aftereffects').addClass('scrolled5');
                    } else {
                    $('div.sidebar').removeClass('scrolled3');
                    $('div.logo_premierepro').removeClass('scrolled4');
                    $('div.logo_aftereffects').removeClass('scrolled5');
                    }
                    } else {
                    $('div#myTopnav ').removeClass('scrolled');
                    $('a').removeClass('scrolled2');

                  }
                });
              function myFunction() {
                  $("#myTopnav").toggleClass('responsive');
                  $("div.sidebar").toggleClass('responsive');

              }
        </script>
```

CSS

```
  .logo_aftereffects {
        background: url('/images/aftereffects_icon.png');
        width: 64px;
        min-height: 64px;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-top: 50px;
        float: left;
        opacity: 0;

  }

  .logo_premierepro {
        background: url('/images/premierepro_icon.png');
        width: 68px;
        min-height: 68px;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-top: 49px;
        float: right;
        opacity: 0;
  }

  .scrolled {
        min-height: 10px;
        color: inherit;
        background: black;
        transition: 0.35s all ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .scrolled2 {
        color: white;
        opacity: 1;
  }

  .scrolled3 {
        transition: .85s all ease-in-out;
        background: #d2a679;
        opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .scrolled4 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 1s all ease-out;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 38%;
  }

  .scrolled5 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 1s all ease-out;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 38%;
  }
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: you should add this css

 `.logo_aftereffects {       
        transition: 1s all ease-in;
   }

    .logo_premierepro {
  transition: 1s all ease-in;
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the "reverse" fade effect, you also need to explicitly provide the `transition` property on your original elements(`.logo_aftereffects` & `.logo_premierepro`).

```
.logo_aftereffects {
        background: url('..');
        width: 64px;
        min-height: 64px;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-top: 50px;
        float: left;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 1s all ease-out; //added
  }

  .logo_premierepro {
        background: url('..');
        width: 68px;
        min-height: 68px;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-top: 49px;
        float: right;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 1s all ease-out; //added
  }
```

Comment: glad to help .. you too :)